# User is not getting the ability to see files in project in VSO

Tags: azure-devops

In VSO I went to a project. And in the project I went to the default team. I added a person to that project. But all they get in the Team Explorer for that project is "Pending Changes" and "Settings".

What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is disconnected.

1. Click Manage connections icon

[image]

2. Click Manage Connections link

[image]

3. Select Server, team project collection and team project
4. Click Connect

Comment: The key part is the user had to log out and back in too.